# Multiplying Values from two different Dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, data-structures, sum

I have two dictionaries which I need to multiply and get the total of, both with the same keys (I need the total of the stock and price of some items).

```
# Create a list "menu" with 4 items
menu = ["sandwich", "burger", "fish", "chips"]
# Create a dictionary "stock" with the stock value for each item in the menu
stock = {"sandwich" : 6, "burger" : 5, "fish" : 6, "chips" : 10}
# Create a dictionary "price" with the price for each item in the menu
price = {"sandwich" : 4.50, "burger" : 6.00, "fish" : 6.50, "chips" : 3.50}

# Get the values from stock and price for each menu item and multiply by eachother
for key in price:
    menu_stock = price[key] * stock[key]
    # Get the sum of these values
    total_stock_worth = sum(menu_stock)

# Print statement with the calculated total stock worth
print("The total stock worth is £" + str("{:.2f}".format(total_stock_worth)))
```

I get the error message (for line 12: total_stock_worth = sum(menu_stock)):
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

The output I'm after is:
The total stock worth is £131.00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sum` function work with `iterable` ex: `list, set` etc.. In your code `menu_stock` is a `float` not an `iterable`.
To solved your problem declare `menu_stock` as a list and `append` the product of each of the `stock` and `price` to it. After the loop, call the `sum` function to calculate the `total_stock_worth`.

Also you don't need to call the `str()` method `format()` does that automatically for you.

**Solution**

```py
# Create a list "menu" with 4 items
menu = ["sandwich", "burger", "fish", "chips"]
# Create a dictionary "stock" with the stock value for each item in the menu
stock = {"sandwich" : 6, "burger" : 5, "fish" : 6, "chips" : 10}
# Create a dictionary "price" with the price for each item in the menu
price = {"sandwich" : 4.50, "burger" : 6.00, "fish" : 6.50, "chips" : 3.50}

# declare menu_stock as list
menu_stock = []

# Get the values from stock and price for each menu item and multiply by eachother
for key in price:
    menu_stock.append(price[key] * stock[key])
    # Get the sum of these values
total_stock_worth = sum(menu_stock)

# Print statement with the calculated total stock worth
print("The total stock worth is £{:.2f}".format(total_stock_worth))
```

Comment: Amazing this has worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: I dislike the recommendation from this answer. Either use `sum` directly with a generator-expression: `total_stock_worth = sum(price[key] * stock[key] for key in price)` or do not use `sum` at all and use a loop to add the values manually: `total_stock_worth=0; for key in price: menu_stock = price[key] * stock[key]; total_stock_worth += menu_stock`. But doing a mix of both and maintaining a list just to finally sum its item is very counterintuitive, and also less efficient, both in time and in space.

Comment: @Stef This code time complexity is ```O(n)```. Can we do better than this?

Comment: @MaxwellD.Dorliea Your code builds a list of length `n`, when no list is needed. So in terms of space complexity, yes, we easily can do better than this.

Comment: @Stef I know for space complexity we can do better but I was only trying to correct the mistake make by the user that ask the question. I didn't wanted to change the whole code but fixed the error. I also wanted him to understand what I did. Moreover him didn't ask for reducing the space complexity. I'm sure him don't have much to do with that for now. Anyways thanks for the suggestion Sir. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

`menu_stock` (in your loop) stores **float** value while [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) function requires its argument to be an ***iterable***. 
So you need to accumulate all products of `price*stock`s before calculating their sum.

Comment: Thanks, I am new to Python so still learning. How do I accumulate the products so they are iterable?

Comment: @mandykg, simply with `total_stock_worth = sum(price[k] * stock[k] for k in price)` - generating accumulated iterable on the fly

Answer (score 0):

To compute the `total_stock_worth` try:

```py
# Create a list "menu" with 4 items
menu = ["sandwich", "burger", "fish", "chips"]
# Create a dictionary "stock" with the stock value for each item in the menu
stock = {"sandwich": 6, "burger": 5, "fish": 6, "chips": 10}
# Create a dictionary "price" with the price for each item in the menu
price = {"sandwich": 4.50, "burger": 6.00, "fish": 6.50, "chips": 3.50}

# Get the values from stock and price for each menu item and multiply by eachother
total_stock_worth = sum(price[m] * stock[m] for m in menu)

# Print statement with the calculated total stock worth
print("The total stock worth is £" + str("{:.2f}".format(total_stock_worth)))
```

Prints:

```
The total stock worth is £131.00
```

Comment: Thanks, when I try this I get SyntaxError: invalid syntax. It seems to have an issue with the word for.

Comment: @mandykg Are you sure you typed it correctly? `total_stock_worth = sum(price[m] * stock[m] for m in menu)`

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

- Use a `for`-loop, and increment `total_stock_worth` with `+=`; or
- Use `sum( )` with a generator-expression.

In your code you tried to mix both, and it fails for two reasons:

- you call `sum` on a single value instead of a sequence of values;
- every time you write `total_stock_worth = ...` you erase the previous value stored in `total_stock_worth`.

Below, the two options:

```py
# Create a list "menu" with 4 items
menu = ["sandwich", "burger", "fish", "chips"]
# Create a dictionary "stock" with the stock value for each item in the menu
stock = {"sandwich" : 6, "burger" : 5, "fish" : 6, "chips" : 10}
# Create a dictionary "price" with the price for each item in the menu
price = {"sandwich" : 4.50, "burger" : 6.00, "fish" : 6.50, "chips" : 3.50}

# OPTION 1: USE A FOR-LOOP AND INCREMENT MANUALLY
total_stock_worth = 0
for key in price:
    menu_stock = price[key] * stock[key]
    total_stock_worth = total_stock_worth + menu_stock

print("The total stock worth is £{:.2f}".format(total_stock_worth))

# OPTION 2: USE SUM() WITH A GENERATOR-EXPRESSION
total_stock_worth = sum(price[key] * stock[key] for key in price)

print("The total stock worth is £{:.2f}".format(total_stock_worth))
```

With both options the output is the same:

```
The total stock worth is £131.00
```

As a matter of personal preference, you can replace:

```py
total_stock_worth = total_stock_worth + menu_stock
```

with:

```py
total_stock_worth += menu_stock
```

where `+=` can be read as "increment by"; those two lines are really equivalent.